# i created a custom table for wordpress website that when i will create or update or delete post or page that time some information stored custom table

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I want to store some information with my new custom table in Wordpress website, whenever admin create update or delete any post or page that time some information store my custom table.
Below my custom table operations

Operations:
id,User_id,operation_type,table_name,row_id,operation_at,created_at,updated_at.

user_id (post_author)
operation_type (add/update/delete etc),
table_name   (which table add/update/delete),
row_id  (post r page own id),
operation_at  (that time when admin add/update/delete),
created_at (operations table current time),
updated_at (operations current time),

how can implement this code?

Thanks

Comment: OK , you described what you wanred. Can you pkease ask a question? Please be mindful that a question has to be specific! Asking us how to implement an entire feature will likely result in your question being closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following hooks:

1. For new post / page creation: [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/)
2. For post update: [post_updated](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/)
3. For post delete: [before_delete_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/before_delete_post/) or [delete_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_post/)

I don't know what do you want to do exactly, but you can insert data with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/

Answer (score 0):

/* You can use these 3 action hooks to have a functionality after update, insert and delete a post respectively. */

```
add_action('post_updated', 'after_update_post', 10, 3 );
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'after_insert_post', 10, 3 );
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'after_delete_post');

function after_update_post($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){
    global $wpdb;
    $date= current_time('mysql');
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'your_table_name';
    $data = array('date_modified' => $date, 'timestamp' => time(), 'operation_type' => 'update', 'post_id' => $post_ID );
    $format = array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d');
    $wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
}
```

/* This function is only for update a post. You have all the hooks for each action just call a function after any specific action */

I hope it will solve your problem.

If you have any problem regarding inserting into a table you might need to look into this. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/